# what is inode for, in FreeBSD or Solaris

Tags: filesystems, freebsd, solaris, inode

I know a little about linux kernel. BUt for Freebsd, the "vnode" actually is similar to the "inode" in Linux kernel.

And there is a "inode" concept in FreeBSD or Solaris.

So my question is: what is "inode" in FreeBSD for?

Below is good to read.

Thank you.

http://hub.opensolaris.org/bin/view/Community+Group+advocacy/solaris-linux-freebsd

> All three operating systems use a data abstraction layer to hide file
>   system implementation details from applications. In all three OSes,
>   you use open, close, read, write, stat, etc. system calls to access
>   files, regardless of the underlying implementation and organization of
>   file data. Solaris and FreeBSD call this mechanism VFS ("virtual file
>   system") and the principle data structure is the vnode, or "virtual
>   node." Every file being accessed in Solaris or FreeBSD has a vnode
>   assigned to it. In addition to generic file information, the vnode
>   contains pointers to file-system-specific information. Linux also uses
>   a similar mechanism, also called VFS (for "virtual file switch"). In
>   Linux, the file-system-independent data structure is an inode. This
>   structure is similar to the vnode on Solaris/FreeBSD. (Note that there
>   is an inode structure in Solaris/FreeBSD, but this is
>   file-system-dependent data for UFS file systems). Linux has two
>   different structures, one for file operations and the other for inode
>   operations. Solaris and FreeBSD combine these as "vnode operations."

Comment: Search engine win: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-kernel-70/difference-between-inode-and-vnode-657954/.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An `inode` is a structure in some file systems that holds a file or directory's metadata (all the information about the file, except its name and data). It holds information about permissions, ownership, creation and modification times, etc.

Systems the offer a virtualised file system access layer (FreeBSD, Solaris, Linux), can support different underlying file systems which may or may not utilise inodes. ReiserFS, for example, doesn't use them, whereas FreeBSD's `ffs2` does. The abstraction layer through which you access the file system provides a single and well-defined interface for file operations, so that applications don't need to know about the differences between different file system implementations.

Comment: I know on Solaris that with UFS, there was a limit for the # of inodes which sometimes caused issues.  This is not supposed to be a problem with ZFS and I've seen tests where directory structures with large amounts of files is faster.