# How does Unix keep track of a user's working directory when navigating the file system?

Tags: filesystems, pwd

Say I log into a shell on a unix system and begin tapping away commands. I initially begin in my user's home directory `~`. I might from there `cd` down to the directory `Documents`.

The command to change working directory here is very simple intuitively to understand: the parent node has a list of child nodes that it can access, and presumably it uses an (optimised) variant of a search to locate the existence of a child node with the name the user entered, and the working directory is then "altered" to match this — correct me if I'm wrong there. It may even be simpler that the shell simply "naively" tries to attempt to access the directory exactly as per the user's wishes and when the file system returns some type of error, the shell displays a response accordingly.

What I am interested in however, is how the same process works when I navigate up a directory, i.e. to a parent, or a parent's parent.

**Given my unknown, presumably "blind" location of `Documents`, one of possibly many directories in the entire file system tree with that name, how does Unix determine where I should be placed next?** Does it make a reference to `pwd` and examine that? If yes, how does `pwd` track the current navigational state?

Comment: See also [Symbolic link recursion - what makes it "reset"?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/79621) where a lot of that is explained

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The other answers are oversimplifications, each presenting only parts of the story, and are wrong on a couple of points.

There are *two* ways in which the working directory is tracked:

- For every process, in the kernel-space data structure that represents that process, the kernel stores two vnode references to the vnodes of the working directory and the root directory for that process.  The former reference is set by the `chdir()` and `fchdir()` system calls, the latter by `chroot()`.  One can see them indirectly in `/proc` on Linux operating systems or via the `fstat` command on FreeBSD and the like:

  ```
  % fstat -p $$|head -n 5
  USER     CMD          PID   FD MOUNT      INUM MODE         SZ|DV R/W
  JdeBP    zsh        92648 text /         24958 -r-xr-xr-x  702360  r
  JdeBP    zsh        92648 ctty /dev        148 crw--w----   pts/4 rw
  JdeBP    zsh        92648   wd /usr/home/JdeBP      4 drwxr-xr-x     124  r
  JdeBP    zsh        92648 root /             4 drwxr-xr-x      35  r
  %
  ```

  When pathname resolution operates, it begins at one or the other of those referenced vnodes, according to whether the path is relative or absolute.  (There is a family of `…at()` system calls that allow pathname resolution to begin at the vnode referenced by an open (directory) file descriptor as a third option.)

  In microkernel Unices the data structure is in application space, but the principle of holding open references to these directories remains the same.
- Internally, within shells such as the Z, Korn, Bourne Again, C, and Almquist shell, the shell *additionally* keeps track of the working directory using string manipulation of an internal string variable.  It does this whenever it has cause to call `chdir()`.

  If one changes to a relative pathname, it manipulates the string to append that name.  If one changes to an absolute pathname, it replaces the string with the new name.  In both cases, it adjusts the string to remove `.` and `..` components and to chase down symbolic links replacing them with their linked-to names.  ([Here is the Z shell's code for that](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/5f6a52c06ca956cf61eacd7f45f270899337d45e/Src/utils.c#L803), for example.)

  The name in the internal string variable is tracked by a *shell variable* named `PWD` (or `cwd` in the C shells).  This is conventionally exported as an environment variable (named `PWD`) to programs spawned by the shell.

These two methods of tracking things are revealed by the `-P` and `-L` options to the `cd` and `pwd` shell built-in commands, and by the differences between the shells' built-in `pwd` commands and both the `/bin/pwd` command and the built-in `pwd` commands of things like (amongst others) VIM and NeoVIM.

```
% mkdir a ; ln -s a b
% (cd b; pwd; /bin/pwd; printenv PWD)
/usr/home/JdeBP/b
/usr/home/JdeBP/a
/usr/home/JdeBP/b
% (cd b; pwd -P; /bin/pwd -P)
/usr/home/JdeBP/a
/usr/home/JdeBP/a
% (cd b; pwd -L; /bin/pwd -L)
/usr/home/JdeBP/b
/usr/home/JdeBP/b
% (cd -P b; pwd; /bin/pwd; printenv PWD)
/usr/home/JdeBP/a
/usr/home/JdeBP/a
/usr/home/JdeBP/a
% (cd b; PWD=/hello/there /bin/pwd -L)
/usr/home/JdeBP/a
%
```

As you can see: obtaining the "logical" working directory is a matter of looking at the `PWD` shell variable (or environment variable if one is not the shell program); whereas obtaining the "physical" working directory is a matter of calling the `getcwd()` library function.

The operation of the `/bin/pwd` program when the `-L` option is used is somewhat subtle.  It *cannot trust* the value of the `PWD` environment variable that it has inherited.  After all, it need not have been invoked by a shell and intervening programs may not have implemented the shell's mechanism of making the `PWD` environment variable always track the name of the working directory.  Or someone may do what I did just there.

So what it does is (as the POSIX standard says) check that the name given in `PWD` yields the same thing as the name `.`, as can be seen with a system call trace:

```
% ln -s a c
% (cd b;  truss /bin/pwd -L 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 | grep -E '^stat|__getcwd')
stat("/usr/home/JdeBP/b",{ mode=drwxr-xr-x ,inode=120932,size=2,blksize=131072 }) = 0 (0x0)
stat(".",{ mode=drwxr-xr-x ,inode=120932,size=2,blksize=131072 }) = 0 (0x0)
/usr/home/JdeBP/b
% (cd b; PWD=/usr/local/etc truss /bin/pwd -L 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 | grep -E '^stat|__getcwd')
stat("/usr/local/etc",{ mode=drwxr-xr-x ,inode=14835,size=158,blksize=10240 }) = 0 (0x0)
stat(".",{ mode=drwxr-xr-x ,inode=120932,size=2,blksize=131072 }) = 0 (0x0)
__getcwd("/usr/home/JdeBP/a",1024)       = 0 (0x0)
/usr/home/JdeBP/a
% (cd b; PWD=/hello/there truss /bin/pwd -L 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 | grep -E '^stat|__getcwd')
stat("/hello/there",0x7fffffffe730)      ERR#2 'No such file or directory'
__getcwd("/usr/home/JdeBP/a",1024)       = 0 (0x0)
/usr/home/JdeBP/a
% (cd b; PWD=/usr/home/JdeBP/c truss /bin/pwd -L 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 | grep -E '^stat|__getcwd')
stat("/usr/home/JdeBP/c",{ mode=drwxr-xr-x ,inode=120932,size=2,blksize=131072 }) = 0 (0x0)
stat(".",{ mode=drwxr-xr-x ,inode=120932,size=2,blksize=131072 }) = 0 (0x0)
/usr/home/JdeBP/c
%
```

As you can see: it only calls `getcwd()` if it detects a mismatch; and it can be fooled by setting `PWD` to a string that does indeed name the same directory, but by a different route.

The `getcwd()` library function is a subject in its own right.  But to précis:

- Originally it was purely a library function, that built up a pathname from the working directory back up to the root by repeatedly trying to look up the working directory in the `..` directory.  It stopped when it reached a loop where `..` was the same as its working directory or when there was an error trying to open the next `..` up.  This would be a lot of system calls under the covers.
- Nowadays the situation is slightly more complex.  On FreeBSD, for example (this being true for other operating systems as well), it *is* a true system call, as you can see in the system call trace given earlier.  All of the traversal from the working directory vnode up to the root is done in a single system call, which takes advantage of things like kernel mode code's direct access to the directory entry cache to do the pathname component lookups much more efficiently.

  However, note that even on FreeBSD and those other operating systems the kernel *does not* keep track of the working directory with a string.

Navigating to `..` is again a subject in its own right.  Another précis:  Although directories conventionally (albeit, as already alluded to, this is *not* required) contain an actual `..` in the directory data structure on disc, the kernel tracks the parent directory of each directory vnode itself and can thus navigate to the `..` vnode of any working directory.  This is somewhat complicated by the mountpoint and changed root mechanisms, which are beyond the scope of this answer.

## Aside

Windows NT in fact does a similar thing.  There is a single working directory per process, set by the `SetCurrentDirectory()` API call and tracked per process by the kernel via an (internal) open file handle to that directory; and there is a set of environment variables that Win32 programs (not just the command interpreters, but *all* Win32 programs) use to track the names of multiple working directories (one per drive), appending to or overwriting them whenever they change directory.

Conventionally, unlike the case with Unix and Linux operating systems, Win32 programs do not display these environment variables to users.  One can sometimes see them in Unix-like subsystems running on Windows NT, though, as well as by using the command interpreters' `SET` commands in a particular way.

## Further reading

- ["`pwd`"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pwd.html).  *The Open Group Base Specifications* Issue 7.  IEEE 1003.1:2008.  The Open Group.  2016.
- ["Pathname Resolution"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_13).  *The Open Group Base Specifications* Issue 7.  IEEE 1003.1:2008.  The Open Group.  2016.
- https://askubuntu.com/a/636001/43344
- [How are files opened in unix?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134975/)
- [what is inode for, in FreeBSD or Solaris](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35672/)
- [Strange environment variable !::=::\ in Cygwin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/251174/)
- [Why does CDPATH not work as documented in the manuals?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418013/)
- [How can I set zsh to use physical paths?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371145/)
- [Going into a directory linked by a link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146843/)

Comment: This is far more than I ever expected. Thank you, and extra thanks for the further reading!

Comment: http://doc.cat-v.org/plan_9/4th_edition/papers/lexnames talks about some of the problems with `..` in the context of Plan9,

Comment: @JdeBP: Perhaps I’m missing something.  You say, “Internally, within …, bash, … and …, the shell *additionally* keeps track of the working directory using string manipulation of an internal string variable.  …, it adjusts the string to remove `.` and `..` components ***and to chase down symbolic links replacing them with their linked-to names.*** …  The name in the internal string variable is tracked by a shell variable named `PWD` …” (emphasis added).  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … But your example shows `PWD` = `…/b` after a `cd b` command, even though `b` is a symbolic link to `a` — so the shell doesn’t “chase down” the `a -> b` link. Did you misstate, or did I misread?

Comment: I simply glossed over a side point, and pointed you to the code for details.  See the various shells' manuals for when and how they decide to chase symbolic links or not.  The Z shell handily calls its shell option that is one part of the decision formula, `CHASE_LINKS`.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel does not keep track of directory or file names; a file or directory is represented in the kernel by an inode/device pair. System calls like `chdir()`, `open()`, etc. take a path as parameter, which can be absolute (e.g. `/etc/passwd`), or relative to the current directory (examples: `Documents`, `..`). When a process executes `chdir("Documents")`, a lookup is done for `Documents` in the current working directory, and the process's working directory is updated to refer to this directory. From the kernel's perspective, there is nothing special in the name "..", it's just a convention in the file system that `..` refers to the parent directory.

The `getcwd()` function is not a system call, but a library function that has to work its way up to the root directory, recording the names of the path components on the way.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, traditionally `cd ..` is much much more simple than `pwd`.  Directories named `..` are placed explicitly into the file system.  The system keeps track of the device/inode of the current directory, so `cd ..` or more accurately the system call `chdir("..")` just entails looking up the name ".." in the file belonging to the current directory's inode and changing the current directory's device/inode to the value found there.

`pwd` (more accurately `/bin/pwd`) follows `..` links successively and reads the respective directories until finding the inode where it came from, assembling the list of those names in reverse until it reaches the root directory (notably not containing a `..` entry).

Now this is the original low-level basic behavior.  Actual shell commands `pwd` instead rely on a variety of techniques caching the current path name.  But at the core, it's only its inode that is actually known.  That implies that once symlinks are used for navigating directories, the current work directory name notions of the current shell and of the system `/bin/pwd` might diverge.