# Inconsistent behavior of Bash's `cd` with symbolic links

Tags: bash, symlink, cd-command

I am currently trying understand the behavior of Bash's `cd` when it comes to symbolic links. By default, `cd` should follow the logical directory structure and should not resolve symbolic links.

`cd` behaves like this in my first example. However, I came up with a second example where `cd` seems to follow the physical structure. Is this expected behavior? What's the difference?

### Setup

```
$ cd
$ mkdir -p test/a/b/c test/d
$ tree test
test
├── a
│   └── b
│       └── c
└── d

4 directories, 0 files
$ cd test/d
$ ln -s ../a/b/c symlink
```

### 1st example

```
$ pwd
/home/hexcabron/test/d
$ tree ..
..
├── a
│   └── b
│       └── c
└── d
    └── symlink -> ../a/b/c

5 directories, 0 files
$ cd symlink/../../a
$ pwd
/home/hexcabron/test/a
```

### 2nd example

```
$ cd ../d
$ pwd
/home/hexcabron/test/d
$ mkdir -p symlink/../e
$ tree ..
..
├── a
│   └── b
│       ├── c
│       └── e
└── d
    └── symlink -> ../a/b/c

6 directories, 0 files
$ cd symlink/../e
$ pwd
/home/hexcabron/test/a/b/e
```

Comment: I'm sorry, could you describe what you expected to happen in the second example please?

Comment: I don't see any unexpected behavior there.  symlink = `test/a/b/c`, so `cd symlink/../e` is the equivalent of `cd test/a/b/c/../e`, which is the equivalent of `cd test/a/b/e`.    In fact, I don't even see any inconsistent behavior.   In both your examples, the behavior is the same.

Comment: I expected it to follow the logical structure and thus try to change to `/home/hexcabron/test/d/e` and fail.

Comment: Ah.  Once you put that trailing slash onto `symlink` so it's `symlink/`, that tells both `mkdir` and `cd` to follow that path *as a directory*, as long as it exists, and as long as it's not a loop of symlinks that point to each other more than 20 times (MAXSYMLINKS defined in bits/param.h)  This is part of the POSIX specification around pathname resolution. http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap04.html#tag_04_11

Comment: @Tim: Shouldn't the `cd` in the first example then also have followed the path as a directory (= physical, not logical), leading to `cd /home/hexcabron/test/a/a` and fail?

Comment: Ah, yes.  I missed the double `..`.  Also, I just tried your setup at home, and on my Ubuntu system, I am unable to duplicate your behavior.  If I `cd symlink`, pwd shows me `test/d/symlink`, and cd `symlink/..` sends me back to `test/d`.

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/413204/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. Assuming you're using bash, `cd` will default to following symbolic links. This behavior can be overridden using the `-P` and `-L` flags which force `cd` to use the physical path and link path respectively.

I assume in your 1st example, `cd` noticed there was no path to directory `a` following the symlink, so it tried the physical path and found the directory. I can't easily find evidence to back up that assumption, but you could follow the logic in the [source](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/cd.def) to see exactly what's going on (it's not that much code).

Comment: This guess is correct , the relevant source code logic bit starts [here](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/cd.def?h=bash-4.4#n571).