# Why do relative paths that traverse a symlink in reverse resolve using the true path?

Tags: linux, bash, symlink, directory-structure

Either I've completely misunderstood something about symlinks (most likely), or their behaviour has changed at some point and I'm now catching up.

I have a script directory that resides somewhere on my file system, let's say `/tmp/scripts` for the sake of this explanation. This script directory is intended be added to an arbitrary project by creating a symlink to it, within the project - e.g. `ln -s /tmp/scripts $(PROJECT)/scripts`. The scripts within this directory expect to find some project-specific info in `../config` (i.e. a subdirectory of the project). However, what I'm finding is that *when scripts are run from within the script directory* they look in `/tmp/config` (which doesn't exist) rather than `$(PROJECT)/config`, resolving the relative path against the *true* location of the script directory, and ignoring the symlink context. This is true even though `cd $(PROJECT)/scripts; pwd` shows the symlink context.

Here's a simple example of this, on Ubuntu 16.04, with Bash 4.3.48:

```
$ mkdir a
$ touch a/apples
$ mkdir -p b/a
$ touch b/a/bananas
$ mkdir -p b/c
$ ln -s b/c c
$ cd c
$ pwd
/home/user/c      # note this does not show '/home/user/b/c'
$ ls ../a
bananas
$ cd ../a
$ ls
apples
```

This surprises me, because it suggests that a process with a working directory behind a symlink does not have the same environment as the process that invoked it.

Perhaps it's always been like this? Why does the script process know that it's not really in `$(PROJECT)/scripts` yet `pwd` does not? Is `pwd` faking it? Can anyone shed some light please?

EDIT: here's a simple practical example, that first sets up the relative directories, then creates a script (in this case a simple Makefile) and then invokes it:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p a
echo "A:=42" > a/Config
mkdir -p b/a
echo "A:=77" > b/a/Config
mkdir -p b/c
ln -sfn b/c c
echo -e "include ../a/Config\nall:\n\t@echo \${A}" > c/Makefile
cd c
make
```

This will output `77` whereas I had hoped it that it might output `42`, as that would be the value set by the project for use by the symlinked Makefile et al. In reality, the directory `b/a` doesn't actually exist, so instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p a
echo "A:=42" > a/Config
mkdir -p b/c
ln -sfn b/c c    
echo -e "include ../a/Config\nall:\n\t@echo \${A}" > c/Makefile    
cd c
make
```

Resulting in:

```
$ ./setup
Makefile:1: ../a/Config: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target '../a/Config'.  Stop.
```

Comment: `cd` is evaluated by your shell, it's not a good test case. `ls` is reading the actual `..` entry.

Comment: Could you give an example of an actual script that exhibits the behaviour you're asking about? Show what happens, and what you expect/what you think used to happen, and if there are any cases that *do* behave as expected (which it sounds like there are) include those too.

Comment: A related question is of course https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/413204/ .

Comment: @MichaelHomer good idea - I've added an example that shows this behaviour using `make`.

Comment: @JdeBP thanks for the link, that's led to some good explanations and helped demystify things a bit. Now I'm wondering how to make all my scripts consistent to use either the Logical path all the time, or the Physical path all the time.

Comment: I really meant to include one of the entries from your `scripts` directory, since that's what's manifesting the problem, rather than a replication script (the original block was mostly fine for that). In particular the element that *when scripts are run from within the script directory* you see the problem would highlight more clearly what's happening with an actual example.

Comment: Not sure why this has been downvoted - it's a valid observation that I explained carefully, with examples, and the info provided here by others might be useful to future readers who encounter this same behaviour. I showed this to several professional programmers and they were all as surprised by this behaviour as I was.

Answer (score 3):

If you like `cd` to behave as you expect, call:

```
cd -P c
```

and `pwd` will print:

```
/home/user/b/c
```

What you see is a problem that is caused by the fact that your shell follows an unhappy POSIX decision and makes `cd -L` the default. This causes the shell to remember the apparent `$PWD` `/home/user/c`. Since the shell command `cd ..` does not call `chdir("..")` but rather shortens the `$PWD` value by one element and then `chdir()`s to that shortened path, `cd ..` gets you back from where you did come.

This is a security risk, as people tend to run e.g.:

```
ls ../
```

and after being happy with the result, then may run:

```
cd ../; rm *.c
```

and remove different files than expected.

Note that the POSIX default is modeled after the default behavior of `ksh88` and at the same time when ksh introduced that default behavior, AT&T decided to implement the safer variant `cd -P` as the default in the Bourne Shell.