# Is working in symlink directory identical to working in the directory directly?

Tags: directory, symlink

In  my home directory, I have a folder named `symlinks` in which all my symlinks live. I've added this folder  to my `CDPATH`, so that I can do:

```
~$ cd FarAwayDirectory
~/symlinks/FarAwayDirectory$
```

I’ve noticed that if I `pwd`, I get:

`~/symlinks/FarAwayDirectory`     ->    **A**

rather than:

`.../.../.../FarAwayDirectory`    ->    **B**

which is what I would've gotten through consecutive `cd`’s.

So my question is: **Is working in directory *A* identical to working in directory *B*?**

Comment: See also: https://superuser.com/a/1316360/334516

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Working in directory A is the same as working in directory B.

A symlink is a special file that points to another file. `~/symlinks/FarAwayDirectory` actually doesn’t have any data of it’s own (except basic file system metadata). Rather, it literally points to the directory you have it symlinked to.

You can test this by creating a file in `~/symlinks/FarAwayDirectory` and confirming the file exists in the full path to the actual directory.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you use the version of `pwd` that is built-in in `bash`, you'll get output A.

But try explicitly invoking a stand-alone binary version of `pwd`:

```
$ /bin/pwd
```

I think you'll see your output B.

Basically this is because `bash` remembers that you arrived to the directory through a symlink, and so presents the path to you in "logical" form (your output A) by default. If you want the "physical" path (your output B) to be presented in all cases like this, you can use `set -P` to make it so.

Or if you want to do it in case-by-case basis, `bash`'s built-in `cd` command also supports the '-L' and '-P' options.

Answer (score 0):

## There is no directory A.

It is a symbolic link, *not a directory*.  The working directory is *the same single directory* in both cases.  The only difference is in the value of the `PWD` variable, which in turn affects what some commands *report* as the name of the current directory.  The built-in `pwd` command in several shells, for example, will report the value of the `PWD` shell variable unless told to ignore it.  The external `pwd` command (if told to do so with the `-L` option) will check that the value of the `PWD` environment variable that it has inherited, and if it checks out as a name for the current directory also uses it.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/413225/5132