# Why pwd does not accept long options like --physical?

Tags: bash, rhel, pwd

When I display the manual for `pwd` command, it says that long options like `--physical` are supported

```
$ man pwd
PWD(1)                           User Commands                          PWD(1)

NAME
       pwd - print name of current/working directory

SYNOPSIS
       pwd [OPTION]...

DESCRIPTION
       Print the full filename of the current working directory.

       -L, --logical
              use PWD from environment, even if it contains symlinks

       -P, --physical
              avoid all symlinks
```

However, it fails when I type the following

```
$ pwd --physical
-bash: pwd: --: invalid option
pwd: usage: pwd [-LP]
```

Why are long options not working for me?

I'm using RHEL 6.4. No alias for pwd is configured. Looks like it's standard pwd:

```
$ which pwd
/bin/pwd
```

Comment: The manual page is for a standalone utility which is not part of bash.

Comment: Use `type` instead of `which`, since `which` only shows commands, while `type` shows keywords, builtins, aliases, functions, and commands (and hashed command paths). For more details see [Why not use “which”? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249/117037)

Comment: In my system `man pwd` has following note: `your shell may have its own version of pwd, which usually supersedes the version described here.  Please refer to your  shell's  documentation for details about the options it supports` at the bottom of `DESCRIPTION` section.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`bash` has a built-in command `pwd` which is what you are using when you simply type `pwd` into your shell.

To get the `pwd` as described by the manpage, you need force use of the external command. You can do this by specifying the full path to the executable (`/bin/pwd` in your case) or by prepending `env` before the line: `env pwd`, which starts the `env` command which can be used to add settings to the environment (but which is not done here) and then `env` starts the command specified. As `env` doesn't have a builtin `pwd`, the "real" `/bin/pwd` is executed.

The advantage of the builtin `pwd` in bash is that `bash` keeps track of the current directory, so getting the value is at zero cost, whereas the external command needs to search up through the filesystem to determine the path, which is much more IO intensive.

Comment: That's not how the external command actually works.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/413225/5132

Comment: BTW: You can also disable the shell builtin (at least in bash) by `enable -n pwd`

Comment: @JdeBP It used to be last time I looked (a long time ago :-) ); and whereas it now uses the `getcwd()` system call, the kernel still traverses the filesystem, which is easier to do in kernel space due to access to relevant data structures, As the linked answer states: "However, note that even on FreeBSD and those other operating systems the kernel does not keep track of the working directory with a string."

Answer (score 11):

That manpage documents `/bin/pwd`, but when you run `pwd` you’re using the shell built-in; see the output of

```
type pwd
```

Your shell’s built-in `pwd` doesn’t support long options (see your shell’s documentation; since you’re using Bash, `help pwd` will provide a summary).