# Shell: Mounting to CWD does not update in shell session

Tags: bash, shell, mount, cwd

When mounting a partition into my CWD (`mount /path/do/devxy $(pwd)`), the current shell session does not recognize it, e.g. `find` does not show any contents of the partition and `umount $(pwd)` succeeds despite me being in the directory (keeping it busy).

Only after explicitly entering into the directory via `cd .` I can browse the files and unmounting fails.

So obviously the information on the changes in my CWD is not passed on. This behaviour is very different from e.g. entering a directory in one session and creating a file into that directory from another one. In this case `find`'s results are up to date.

So how does the shell determine where it is and why is the mounting not visible immediately?

Using `GNU bash, version 5.0.3(1)` on `debian 10`.

---

Considered solved: please check comments.

Comment: TL;DR: the kernel keeps track of the process's cwd - and it can distinguish between X, and Y mounted on X.

Comment: This does not seem to fully answer the question, but I think it points in the right direction: the `inode` information seems not to be updated until a proper directory change, i.e. `ls -id .` changes after `cd .` - and so does the output of `lsof | grep mnt`. I assume `inode` is the central property to look at here and consider this answered.

Comment: By this I meant the linked [duplicate's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/413225/123460)

Comment: I think the fact that `cd .` worked is confusing. I suggest that if it did, it is because your shell is doing something other than literally `chdir(".")`.  You could run `python` and run `import os`, `os.system("sudo mount ...")`, `os.chdir(".")`, `os.system("ls -id .")`. Or in another window, you could run `strace -p PID` where PID is the value of `echo $$` in the shell you run the `cd .`, and it will show the exact system calls the shell makes.

Comment: ... ah.  As I see the linked answer points out, most shells do string manipulation to maintain a "logical" current directory name.  This allows `cd ..` to go "back" after you did `cd foo` even when foo is a symbolic link.  It appears that `cd .` is doing something similar.

Comment: `cd .` was not the problem, it could have been `cd ../dir`, `cd /path/to/dir` or `cd $(cwd)`, too - I wondered about the missing update of my CWD when not "changing" paths.

Comment: To be clearer: I think it is confusing that `cd .` in your shell enters the new mounted directory, but `ls .` or `find .` do not show the new mounted directory contents.

Comment: @Fiximan I think what sourcejedi is trying to say is that `cd .` should ideally be a no-op. If the system call `chdir(".")` were executed, you won't see the updated (mounted) directory, but the old, underlying one. Instead, the shell sees `.` and replaces it with the full path that it has kept track of internally. (Try `strace -e chdir bash -c 'cd .'`, for example).

Comment: @muru Now I understand. Just like the different outcomes of `find .` vs. `find /path/to/dir`. Valid point, indeed.